# Is if statement optimized to not call recursive functions if first condition is false?

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion

Consider the scenario:

```
int fun(node* a, node* b){
    if(a == NULL && b == NULL) return 0;
    if( (a->data == b->data) && (fun(a->left) == fun(b->left)) && (fun(a->right) == fun(b->right)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

If we met a condition like if `a->data != b->data`, then will the recursive call be made to `(fun(a->left) == fun(b->left))` and `(fun(a->right) == fun(b->right))` or will it directly say false for the condition?

Comment: This has nothing to do with optimization. The evaluation semantics of if statements are a fundamental part of the core language rules.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, and it's not asking about short-circuit evaluation. It's asking about recursive comparisons of multiple structure fields when those fields aren't explicitly specified.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `if` statement, but rather with evaluation of logical operators. The answer would be applicable in any context.

Comment: `if(a == NULL && b == NULL) return 0;` contains a logical error.

Comment: @KerrekSB Eh, it happens to everyone. It shouldn't too often though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so `fun(a->left)` and other functions on the right-hand side of `&&` won't be called if `a->data == b->data` evaluates to false.

Comment: Awesome. Thank You!!!

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to accept this or another answer if it answers your question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No. The comparison will *only* be made for the items you specify. You would need to create a function to do a recursive comparison on your nodes, or to compare multiple fields within your node structure.

```
int nodes_equal(node* a, node* b){

    if ((a->data != b->data) || (a->left != b->left) || (a->right != b->right))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```